# RAD Studio 2009 Ctrl+Z Buffer Corruption Bug

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, corruption, data-loss

Now this has happened to me twice this week alone: when I press Ctrl+Z a number of times in RAD Studio 2009, the editor buffer gets corrupted. The current and nearby lines get filled with nonsense data, and sometimes a breakpoint is created (autobugically). And there is a `EAccessViolation`in the IDE, which then terminates. All unsaved code is inevitably lost.

[[image]
(High-Res)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/RADCtrlZ.png)

Is there a cure?

Comment: What's the QC number for this bug? If there's a cure, it should be documented there.

Comment: I already logged a bug in QC #81814. But cannot reproduce it anymore and the status is "Need Feedback". Maybe you can add more details in QC on that?

Comment: I've been noticing this since Delphi 5! It still does this?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [IDEFixPack](http://andy.jgknet.de/fixpack) for Delphi 2009 addresses the undo editor buffer corruption bug (and some other bugs). This bug was fixed in Delphi 2010 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got all the updates installed then there's probably no fix, in that version at least.  I believe it got fixed in D2010, though.